# OpenMP C++ program with Vectors

Tags: c++, openmp

I wrote a OpenMP program in C++ which basically finds the suffix-prefix overlap of a given length. All my strings are stored in a vector and I have two for loops for checking the overlap (all against all). I am trying to make the for loop parallel, but it does not improve the time. Following is my program

```
    vector<string> Reads; // contains all strings 
    vector<int> *AdjList = new vector<int>[Reads.size()];
    vector<int> *OLL = new vector<int>[Reads.size()];

     // int i,j;
    /*# pragma omp parallel \
      shared ( AdjList, OLL ) \
      private ( i, j )*/
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<Reads.size(); i++){
      string suff = Reads.at(i).substr(Reads.at(i).length() - minOLL, minOLL);
      for(int j=0; j<Reads.size(); j++){
        if(i != j){
          size_t found = rabin_karp(suff, Reads.at(j));
          if(found != -1){
            string pref1 = Reads.at(j).substr(0, found);
            string suff1 = Reads.at(i).substr(Reads.at(i).length() - minOLL - found, found);
            if(pref1.compare(suff1) == 0){
              AdjList[i].push_back(j);
              OLL[i].push_back(found + minOLL);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I guess `reduction` might help, but I am clueless about how to use it

Comment: Have you enabled OpenMP in Visual Studio compilation settings `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support`? If you're using not Visual Studio, what IDE do you use? I would also recommend using `#pragma omp critical` block inside `if(pref1.compare(suff1) == 0)` condition, because `AdjList` and `OLL` are shared variables.

Comment: I use Mac Terminal and Vi editor, use C++11 compiler
`g++ -g -O3 -fopenmp -std=c++0x `

Comment: try this code to check if OpenMP running: `#pragma omp parallel` (newline) `{ std::cout << 1; }` How many `1` do you have. If only one 1, then OpenMP is not running, and you're using single CPU.

Comment: Code looks good enough to me. How do you measure the time to be able to say that "it does not improve the time"?

Comment: @slavanap OpenMP is running, I tried other simple programs. Also I checked your piece of code and it is printing 1111111111111111.

Comment: @Gilles When I compared the code with and without OMP, the execution times were almost same.

Comment: Which times? CPU times? Elapsed times? How do you measure them?

Comment: I tried with a small input file and used `time` command and got the following`real         0m0.341s`
`user 0m0.322s`
`sys         0m0.001s`

Comment: Just enclose the relevant part of your code (the one that is parallelised) with calls to `omp_get_wtime()` and print the result. This way you really see if you get some speed-up or not by changing the number of OpenMP threads.

Comment: I see !! Let me try that. Thanks !!

Comment: @CPP_NEW you calculate time with wrong tool. And with this tool times will be same, because `time` command sums up times the app run on **ALL** CPU cores! The app runs faster, but consumes more CPU time because it uses more of its cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.since size of strings may be different you may use schedule(dynamic) so the tasks dynamically assigned to threads. 2. you can split inner loop into two loops to get rid of if statement. 3. substr is not a good choice because leads to creation of new string so you may use  and save character positions to speed the code. However below applied 1, 2 mentioned cases:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(int i=0; i<Reads.size(); i++){
  string suff = Reads.at(i).substr(Reads.at(i).length() - minOLL, minOLL);
  for(int j=0; j< i; j++){
      size_t found = rabin_karp(suff, Reads.at(j));
      if(found != -1){
        string pref1 = Reads.at(j).substr(0, found);
        string suff1 = Reads.at(i).substr(Reads.at(i).length() - minOLL - found, found);
        if(pref1.compare(suff1) == 0){
          AdjList[i].push_back(j);
          OLL[i].push_back(found + minOLL);
        }
      }
  }
  for(int j=i+1; j< Reads.size(); j++){
      size_t found = rabin_karp(suff, Reads.at(j));
      if(found != -1){
        string pref1 = Reads.at(j).substr(0, found);
        string suff1 = Reads.at(i).substr(Reads.at(i).length() - minOLL - found, found);
        if(pref1.compare(suff1) == 0){
          AdjList[i].push_back(j);
          OLL[i].push_back(found + minOLL);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! Yes, I was about to change the `substring`. Now it works but I am just wondering if it is the best solution. My input size is 40~50gb, so with this code it also takes lots of time (using 50 threads)

Comment: The size of the strings are not so different. The lengths are between 100 - 110.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

class Monitorius {
private:
    int M[50];
    int count = 0;
    int suma = 0;
public:
    Monitorius()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            M[i] = 0; // nusinulinamas masyvas
    }

    // Funkcijos ---------------------------------------

    void Prideti(int skaicius) 
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            M[count] = skaicius;
            count++;
            Suma();
        }
    }

    void Suma() 
    {
        suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            suma += M[i];
        }
        cout << "Suma: " << suma << endl;
    }
};

void paleistiGijas(Monitorius *monitorius) {
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(5)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            monitorius->Prideti(i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Monitoriaus sukurimas bei giju paleidimas
    Monitorius *monitorius = new Monitorius();

    // Pradedamas giju darbas
    paleistiGijas(monitorius);

    // Atlaisvinama atmintis
    delete(monitorius);

    return 0;
}
```